# Why Maclaurin Series instead of some other point?

Tags: calculus

This may be a trivial question but I need to confirm my guess... I noticed that the Taylor series centered at $x=0$ series comes up a lot more than Taylor series centered at other points (e.g. it is commonly used that $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + \cdots$). Is this soley because the series "looks nice" at $x=0$ and no other particular reason? Can we say that the series of $e^x$ centered at other points equal the series mentioned above?

Comment: Those series are no special case. You can transform every Taylor-series into a Maclaurin series with a simple shift.

Comment: I would give another reason why $0$ is often used as the reason mentioned in the accepted answer : The derivates often can particular easy be calculated at $0$.

Comment: Do not try to use the Maclaurin series for $\log x$.  In that case, it is more common to use the Taylor series centered at $1$.  $$\log x = (x-1) -\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3}(x-1)^3+\dots\qquad |x|<1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series at points other than $0$ will of course be different (check the definition).

The specific case of the taylor expansion at $0$ is common since many applications are interested in the behavior of the function near $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I really needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with dmh's answer. The function $e^x$ is interesting for a large number of reasons:

- It is its own derivative, so it helps solve a bunch of DEs,
- It can be used to easily define exponentiation of one real number to another (because, for example, $2^\pi$ obviously can't be defined easily with repeated multiplication),
- It can be used to find an anti-derivative to $\frac{1}{x}$,

and more. It isn't particularly interesting around $0$.

So why do we tend to prefer the Maclaurin series? Well, take a look at the Taylor series around $x = a$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^a}{n!}(x - a)^n.$$
Let's suppose that I wanted to estimate $e^3$ using a Taylor series. If I attempt this with the Maclaurin series, I would be calculating:
$$1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{27}{6} + \frac{81}{24} + \ldots$$
I would have to stop at some point, and I could use Taylor's theorem to decide when to do so, but I would essentially be adding a bunch of rational numbers. If I wanted to, and had the patience, I could do this by hand, using algorithms I learned in primary school! And using Taylor's theorem, I would be guaranteed whatever error margin I required.

If I use the Taylor series at, say $a = 1$, then I am summing,
$$e + \frac{2e}{1} + \frac{4e}{2} + \frac{8e}{6} + \frac{16e}{24} + \ldots$$
I can't calculate this so easily, because I don't have the value of $e$. In order to calculate it properly, I'd have to compute $e$ up to some precision sufficient for me to calculate $e^3$ to my desired precision. I'd have to work out what that precision would be (though, admittedly, it's not too difficult), because with an insufficiently precise approximation of $e$, I won't be able to calculate $e^3$ to my desired approximation.

Essentially, it just means that practically using the Taylor series is more work.

It's also worth noting that to compute the Taylor series at $x = a$, then what we are really doing is using $e^x = e^a \cdot e^{x - a}$, computing $e^{x - a}$ using the Maclaurin series for $e^x$. So, the Taylor series is basically the same series multiplied by a factor of $e^a$, making it essentially not any more interesting or useful than the Maclaurin series.

Comment: If you calculate $e$ by a rational number $r$ with precision say better than $0.01$ i.e. $0< e-r< 0.01, $ then $r^3$  will be an estimate of $e^3$ with precision better than $0.01(3r^2+0.03\cdot r +0.0001).$ However this is not very effective as calculating $r^3$ can be painful.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I was imagining calculating $e^a$ with the Maclaurin series anyway (probably $a = 1$ was not the most instructive example).

Comment: I find your example instructive, showing an advantage of the MacLaurin series of $e^x$ over some other manipulations. Especially if the approximation of $e$ is given in the decimal system, the calculation of the third power and putting it in a decimal form takes an effort.